# Adding IP addresses to IIS Virtual SMTP server en masse - is it possible?

Tags: iis, smtp, windows-server-2003

So, here's the problem: I have to configure `Connection Control IIS virtual SMTP server` on **Windows Server 2003**, to be exact, which IP addresses can use the server. So, I run `IIS Manager`, open S`MTP Virtual Server Properties`, open `Access` tag, click on `Connection Control` -> `Add...` And I can only add a single IP address, or a range, or a domain. And I have a lot of addresses to add, so adding single IP addresses is not efficient, and for other reasons I can't add range or a domain.
Is there any way (be it an application, editing text files or running a batch script, or writing myself a `C++/C#` application) to mass add these addresses?
I'd be very grateful if someone could help me with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP address restrictions are held in the [IPSecurity property of the IIS Metabase](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cde669f1-5714-4159-af95-f334251c8cbd.mspx?mfr=true).

As for modifying this programatically, this page looks like it may help you out: http://obligatorymoniker.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/technique-to-change-any-iis-6-properties-programatically/, specifically the bit under the heading "Import IP Security.vbs" looks like it ought to be a good starting point.